# How Can I Fix A HTML Display Error (My Text Drops Down Unexpectedly)

Tags: html, css, layout, formatting

So what I'm trying to do is create a mock up for my own little website in HTML. So everything been going good until just now. What I want to do is display an image and then a title and description next to it, sort of like what youtube does.

Example: [image: What I'm trying to create]

So the way I have it right now it works perfectly if the text doesn't have to drop down to a new line.

Example of it working:[image: It works when my title and description are short]

However, if one of them is too long, everything gets messed up, example of messed up: [image: It messed up if my title is too long]

I set up a JS fiddle to make it easier for you guys. However remember I'm designing with bootstrap so the reason the CSS is so long is because it includes the full bootstrap, however only the first 57 lines is my custom written css. Anyway, if anyone could help me so that when my title or my description is too long it will drop onto the next line like youtube does.

My HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
        <title>Comments</title> 
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="logo">
            <img height="70" width="200" src="/img/logo.png">
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="leftBar">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>Mini Title</h3>
                    </div>

                    <hr/>

                    <div class="contentLink">
                        <div class="smallContentImage">
                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zesaMhG.gif">
                        </div>

                        <div class="smallContentText">
                            <h5>Title Goes Here</h5>

                            <em>
                                Other Informati
                            </em>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightBox">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1>Title For Content</h1>
                    </div>
                    <p> CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

MY CSS

```
body {

    background #FAFAFA;
}


.title {

    text-align: center;
}

.logo {

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.leftBar
{
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rightBox 
{
    margin-left: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

.contentLink
{
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.smallContentImage {

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    float:left;
}

.smallContentText {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: fixed;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BjSv8/

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `width:fixed`. You need to make sure the widths of the two content items add up to the width of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you used em instead of div.
If you could use 'div' instead of 'em' and define the width , then your problem could be solved.

```
<div  style="word-wrap:break-word;border:1px solid red; width:100px">
Other Information goes here
</div>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BjSv8/1/